# PyQt5: Dynamically adding checkboxes using a push button

Tags: python-3.x, pyqt5

In PyQt5, How can I add a checkedbox everytime I click a pushbutton?

Each time I click a push button, it should generate a check box.

### Major lines I am using:

```
self.pushButton_ok.clicked.connect(self.addCheckbox())

def addCheckbox(self):
    checkBox = QtWidgets.QCheckBox()
```

I don't understand what should I further do!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try it:

```
from PyQt5 import QtWidgets, QtGui, QtCore

class Window(QtWidgets.QWidget):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(Window, self).__init__(parent)

        self.vlayout = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout()
        self.pushButton_ok = QtWidgets.QPushButton("Press me", self)
        self.pushButton_ok.clicked.connect(self.addCheckbox)
        self.vlayout.addWidget(self.pushButton_ok)

        self.checkBox = QtWidgets.QCheckBox(self)
        self.vlayout.addWidget(self.checkBox)
        self.setLayout(self.vlayout)

    def addCheckbox(self):
        #checkBox = QtWidgets.QCheckBox()
        self.vlayout.addWidget(QtWidgets.QCheckBox()) 

application = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
window = Window()
window.setWindowTitle('Dynamically adding checkboxes using a push button')
window.resize(250, 180)
window.show()
sys.exit(application.exec_())
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks! It worked perfectly. The major mistake I was making is that I was not creating a lyout.